# Spring java.io.FileNotFoundException: /u01/

Tags: spring, postgresql

I am beginner in spring and postgres. I have setup project in spring and postgres server. It can link already but when I run, I got this error. May I know where I should debug? I am totally lost where to start.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /u01/atLive/log/atlive-newsfeed.log (No
>   such file or directory)   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native
>   Method)   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
>     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)   at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:133)    at
>   org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)

Comment: Can you post some more details? As of now, your information seems to be inadequate. All I can infer is that some file is missing!!!

Comment: Definitely. I wish I could provide you more. But I don't know where to start for this spring project. What I can give is those error message. How shall I debug?

Comment: Not much to go on here, but it could be a log4j configuration problem.